# How to respond to changes in auth state in @aws-amplify/ui-react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-amplify

Using the older `aws-amplify-react`, in order to redirect the user to the requested URL after successful login, I had:

```
<Authenticator
  onStateChange={authState => {
    if (authState === 'signedIn') {
      const { from } = this.props.location.state || {
        from: {
          pathname: '/',
          search: ''
        }
      };
      this.props.history.replace(from.pathname + from.search);
    }
  }}
/>
```

From the [documentation](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/) for the new version (`@aws-amplify/ui-react`) I see how to [access the auth state](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator?platform=react#access-auth-state) with the `useAuthenticator` hook, but no built-in facility to handle changes in this state. Is it not supported and I'm now expected to implement my own change detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed the hook `useAuthenticator` can return `route` that represents the current `authState`:

```
const { route } = useAuthenticator(context => [context.route]);

if (route === "authenticated"){
   
    const location = useLocation();
    const history = useHistory();

    const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: '/', search: '' } }; 
    history.replace(from.pathname + from.search);
}
```

Comment: Could you update this so that we can see how it is used in context? I'm getting errors that it must be used inside an Authenitcator.Provider and I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @CaseSilva it means that the component that you want to use the `useAuthenticator` hook in, has to be wrapped by <Authenticator.Provider>.
Ideally, you would wrap most or even all of your component tree in your src/App.tsx (similarly to the way you wrap your main App component with Context providers).